# Does casting a CopyOnWriteArrayList to a List cause it to lose its concurrency guaranties?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, copy-on-write

The above (title) is my main concern. And the case is

```
public class MyClass{
  CopyOnWriteArrayList<Stuff> min;
  ...
  public List<Stuff> get(){
    return min;
  }
}
```

Is the resulting List obtained from `get()` a liability? Does it affect what happens to `min` or is it its own copy? So for example, if I am iterating over the result of `get()` what's the effects?

Also while we are at it, how about the opposite? If I do

```
List<Stuff> stuffs = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
addABunchOfItems(stuffs);
CopyOnWriteArrayList safeStuff = (CopyOnWriteArrayList) stuffs;
```

What's the status of `safeStuff` and `stuffs` after the third line, concerning concurrency supports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList safeStuff = (CopyOnWriteArrayList) stuffs;
```

will not work, it will raise a compile error; an `ArrayList` is not a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

As to "casting" a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to a `List`, in fact you "don't", since `CopyOnWriteArrayList` *implements* the `List` interface.

Which means it respects the `List` contract; but internally, it is still a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and no, concurrency guarantees are not lost. In fact you'll initiate one using:

```
final List<Whatever> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Note that while there are no dedicated contracts (interfaces) for concurrent implementations of `List` or `Set`, there is one for `Map`s: [ConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html). Which does not mean you are *forced* to use, for instance:

```
final ConcurrentMap<Whatever> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

if you do not *need* access to the specific methods of `ConcurrentMap`.

Answer (score 3):

Casting an object to a different type doesn't change the type of the object. If the object being cast is unable to be cast, a `ClassCastException` will be raised at runtime. You need to instead create a new `CopyOnWriteArrayList` object like

```
List<Stuff> stuffs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Stuff>();
```

In the first example `min` will always be a able to be referenced like a `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Stuff>` returning it as a `List<Stuff>` doesn't change its type.

Comment: Many thanks for helping. +1. But the other person answered first -- by a few seconds apparently. I wish I could accept both answers, though.

Comment: @PoutonGerald you don't have to accept the first answer, accept the answer you think is the best ;)

Comment: @fge: Agreed. Also no hard feelings if my answer isn't chosen, this site isn't meant to be about egos, but helping people learn :)

Comment: You guys are awesome! I love Stackoverflow! Thank you so much.